# Bash - temporary files appear after sed

Tags: bash, file, sed, temporary

in my script i edit a file by using "sed":

```
sed -i -e /NumberOfEntries=*/d "$playlist_name" > /dev/null   # deletes "NumberOfEntries"-line
sed -i -e '/^$/d' "$playlist_name" > /dev/null   # deletes all empty lines
```

This works just fine but while execution (and shortly after) there are one or two temporary files named something like "sedJjHEt2" (the string after sed changes everytime i run the script). The file is marked with a lock and red X-Symbol.

Is there a way to turn this off or am I missing something that I need to adjust? Or is this because of the "-i" Option?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the "-i" Option.
once you use "-i", sed will create a temporary, and then replace the original file with the temporary file.